# Not showing available wifi networks

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet

There were many questions regarding no wifi adapter found. But all of them. Required internet connection.

Whenever I reboot the computer, it shows no wifi adapter found, after some time, the wifi symbol is there, but it cannot show available wifi networks. Visible networks just doing scanning for the whole time.

How to resolve this. I'm writing this from a mobile cannot use internet on the machine due to unavailability of Ethernet/lan connection.

```
user@userHP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**EDIT:** doing `sudo nmcli dev wifi rescan` shows `Error: Scanning not allowed while unavailable or activating.`

kernel version: `Linux 5.3.0-64-generic` and OS is ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: The output is well formatted and long, can I paste the screenshot? Not screen shot sorry but image

Comment: It shouldn't be long if you ran the correct command. It is easier to paste the text and format it by the `{}` icon above.

Comment: But I'm writing from a mobile phone not using that machine as cannot connect to internet.

Comment: You can always connect your phone using a USB cable and have internet connection in Ubuntu if you are using Ubuntu? Are you?

Comment: Yes i'm using Ubuntu

Comment: Didn't know that can be done.. Let me. Try that too

Comment: @Pilot6 very very thanks, I really forgot this way of using the internet. I might have used this in the past but today I wasted my whole day in figuring out this problem and couldn't do my work.

Comment: anybody found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

On UBUNTU desktop:

Sofware & update

Additional Drivers

Select correct driver.

Work fine on XFR E6420